# Correct work with UIPickerVIew with two numbers components

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipickerview

I want to choose in the first component number five (for example) and want the second component are automatically displayed digit +1 from the selected digit in the first component (i.e. six), and to a second component retired numbers to five (or another if I choose).

How can I do this correctly?

Now my code is empty:

```
var numbers: [Int] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if component == 0 {
        return numbers.count
    } else {
        return numbers.count
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if component == 0 {
        return "\(numbers[row])"
    } else {
        return "\(numbers[row])"
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this if I understand your question correctly

```
 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
     if component == 0 {
        componentOne = numbers.filter { (a) -> Bool in
            return a > numbers[row]
        }
        pickerView.reloadComponent(1)
        pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 1, animated: true)
    }
 }
```

And use componentOne in the dataSource methods.

I'm not sure what you have to do in the edge case but you can choose.

Comment: how do I remove numbers from the second component after selecting a numbers from the first component?

Comment: pickerView.reloadComponent(1) but you need to change the list of your component :)

Comment: @ДмитрийДеникаев I update the answer, try with the new code and just use another list of numbers for the second component, is there is some selection you need to update the second array and to reload the component.